# Compare all unique pairs in java Collection

Tags: java

I have a collection of type `Collection<Pair<classA, Collection<classB>>>`. Now I want to do something with every possible pair in the collection and I dont want to repeat pairs ie if I have compared [a,b], I dont want to comapre [b,a]. One solution I was thinking was to make a multimap from collection and then comapre all unique pairs, but it seems we cant use index vise element in map also, i mean something like get(i)

```
for(int i = 0; i<map.size()-1; i++)
for(int j = i+1; j<map.size()-1; j++)
dosomething(multimap.getvalue(i), multimap.getValue(j));
```

Please help me in solving this problem. Have used a lot of mind and did a lot of searching, but unable to figure out. Hope some geniuses can help me here.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Wait.  Are a and b the same type, here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on the types here, but I'd create a class called `UnorderedPair`:

```
class UnorderedPair {
  Object a; // or whatever type should go here
  Object b;
  public int hashCode() { return a.hashCode() + b.hashCode(); }
  public boolean equals(Object o) { 
    if (o instanceof UnorderedPair) {
      UnorderedPair other = (UnorderedPair) o;
      return (a.equals(other.a) && b.equals(other.b))
          || (a.equals(other.b) && b.equals(other.a));
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then you can just use a `Set` to track which pairs have been seen already:

```
Set<UnorderedPair> seen = new HashSet<UnorderedPair>();
...look at a and b...
UnorderedPair p = new UnorderedPair(a, b); // or a factory would be nicer
if(seen.add(p)) {
  // this is a new pair
  doThingWith(a, b);
}
```